# Apple AirPods watt hour meaning

Tags: ratings

I have a part of Apple's product information sheet and I was wondering if I can make an assumption :

[image]

[image]

I am wondering if I can say : "hmm, if the Wh rating of AirPods Charging Case is 1.52Wh, then a 5V adaptor would supply 1.52 / 5 ~= 300mAh and make it full in a little over an hour since the charging case has the capacity of 398mAh."

I am just wondering if this is an educated approach.

Comment: You are mixing mA and mAh. It only says the total energy both devices have, no info on how fast they can transfer it. You can only assume that the fully charged case can fully charge the AirPods (and that is, if the margin is higher than the losses).

Comment: No it's not. The charging case decide how much current it will draw from the power source. You need to either read its spec sheet or test it.

Comment: Can you give me a simple example on how you guys would do if everything was given by a company? I just want to know how to estimate the time it takes for something to charge up that's all. It seems pretty interesting to me.

Comment: They would provide data of how much maximum current it could draw from the power source, and also the voltage. You multiply the two together you get the watt, with the watt hour divided by which you get the hour. That's your lower bound. In practice some energy will be wasted (10% would be a reasonable guess), and the charger won't charge at full speed all the way, either (the beginning and end would be slower to protect the battery) so expect it to be longer. Like I said if everything were given by the manufacturer or designer, charging time should be among it already.

Answer (score 1):

> I am wondering if I can say : "hmm, if the Wh rating of AirPods Charging Case is 1.52Wh, then a 5V adaptor would supply 1.52 / 5 ~= 300mAh

Your calculations are correct if we ignore losses. 300 mAh at 5 V = 1.5 Wh and this is the energy removed during discharge so that has to be put back in during charging. The problem is that there will also be some heat generated in the battery so this has to be included in the calculations. 10% power loss is probably about right.

> ... and make it full in a little over an hour since the charging case has the capacity of 398mAh."

- I'm not sure what a "charging case" is.
- You have assumed in your calculation that the battery will charge at a one-hour rate. This may not be the case and it is not specified in the table you posted. It could be a 2.5 h rate or any other value chosen by the manufacturer. The charge rate will be determined by the battery management system (BMS) rather than by the recharge power supply.